# Normalized values, when summed are more than 1

Tags: linux, python-2.7, normalization, multiplication

I have two files:

File 1:

```
  TOPIC:topic_0 1294
  aa 234
  bb 123

  TOPIC:topic_1 2348
  aa 833
  cc 239
  bb 233
```

File 2:

```
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
```

This is just the format of my files. Basically, when the second column (omitting the first "TOPIC" line) is summed for each topic, it constitutes to 1 as they are the normalized values. Similarly, in file 2, the values are normalized and hence they also constitute to 1.

I perform multiplication of the values from file 1 and 2. The resulting output file looks like:

```
aa 231
bb 379
cc 773
```

The second column when summed of the output file should give 1. But few files have values little over 1 like 1.1, 1.00038. How can I precisely get 1 for the output file? Is it some rounding off that I should do or something?

PS: The formats are just examples, the values and words are different. This is just for understanding purposes. Please help me sort this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python stores floating point decimals in base-2.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

This means that some decimals could be terminating in base-10, but are repeating in base-2, hence the floating-point error when you add them up.

This gets into some math, but imagine in base-10 trying to express the value 2/6.  When you eliminate the common factors from the numerator and denominator it's 1/3.

It's 0.333333333..... repeating forever.  I'll explain why in a moment, but for now, understand that if only store the first 16 digits in the decimal, for example, when you multiply the number by 3, you won't get 1, you'll get .9999999999999999, which is a little off.

This rounding error occurs whenever there's a repeating decimal.

Here's why your numbers don't repeat in base-10, but they do repeat in base-2.

Decimals are in base-10, which prime factors out to 2^1 * 5^1.  Therefore for any ratio to terminate in base-10, its denominator must prime factor to a combination of 2's and 5's, and nothing else.

Now let's get back to Python.  Every decimal is stored as binary.  This means that in order for a ratio's "decimal" to terminate, the denominator must prime factor to only 2's and nothing else.

Your numbers repeat in base-2.

1/10 has (2*5) in the denominator.
2/10 reduces to 1/5 which still has five in the denominator.
3/10... well you get the idea.

Comment: can you elaborate a little please? am a budding programmer. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I wrote up my explanation ad-hoc, but I have also linked to the original Python documentation on the subject which is better formatted and planned out.  If you read my answer and the Python answer and are still confused, go ahead and post another comment, and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I understand the concept. So, how do I avoid it?

Comment: You could multiply everything by a factor and then divide at the end.  A factor of 10 would work in your case.  You could also use the "round" function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborate explanation :) Problem solved :)